# Instance of a class within the argument of another class instance

Tags: php, class

Can someone please explain what it means to have a class instance within the argument of another class instance:

```
$controller = new controllerObject(new dependenciesObject());
```

I understand the basics of classes and class instances but have never seen code like the above before. What does it mean? The controllerObect is a class so what does it mean to pass it an object instance in the argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this means is that the `controllerObject` constructor accepts an object of type `dependenciesObject`.

You instantiate a `dependenciesObject` and use it as an argument to instantiate a `controllerObject`, which is assigned to `$controller`. If it helps you understand, this is equivalent to:

```
$dependency = new dependenciesObject();
$controller = new controllerObject($dependency);
unset($dependency);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is assigning $controller an instance of controllerObject.

As you said controllerObject is a class with a constructor that needs a reference to an object  of :dependenciesObject type.

```
     class controllerObject 
      {
           function __construct(dependanciesObject $dependancies)
            { 
                //etc
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

It just means that the `controllerObject` gets another object passed to its constructor. By doing it like this - instead of instantiating a `dependenciesObject` in a separate variable - you will not create a global variable for the passed object, keeping the number of global variables to a minimum.

An example would be to pass a database object to the `controllerObject` if the `controllerObject` cannot function without it.

Answer (score 0):

Same as passing any other argument to a constructor.. `new controllerObject(5)` for instance.

If it helps understanding, use a temporary variable:

```
$dependencies = new dependenciesObject();
$controller = new controllerObject($dependencies);
```